# Can I travel to Canada if my visa and passport expire a month after I plan to leave?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, visa-expiration

I am an Indian, my Indian passport expires in Septemeber, my Canadian visa also expires on the same date of my passport expiry. Are my passport and visa valid if I  travel to canada in June and stay until August? Or shall I have to get my passport renewed? If so, is my Canadian visa still valid in my old passport or shall I have to get a new visa in my new passport?

Comment: Just check with your local Canadian embassy. They definitely have this information.

Comment: @Indra local embassies are frequently a lot less informative than Travel.SE :)

Answer (score 4):

The only requirement for your passport validity when visiting Canada is that it is valid for the whole of your intended stay. The expiry of your visa is the last day you can **enter** Canada.

So both your passport and visa are fine for your visit.

Answer (score -1):

It's generally recommended that you have a passport valid for 6 months after your travel date to ensure it doesn't expire while you're abroad in case of a travel delay. Legally though your visa is still valid up until the expiry date printed on the visa, even if you renew your passport. Most countries allow you to keep your old passport after a renewal just for such a purpose, so make sure to check with the Indian passport office if this is possible. Once your visa expires, you'll have to apply for a new one.

Comment: Canada does not have a requirement that your passport be valid for six months.

Comment: @DJClayworth Correct, it's not a legal requirement, but it's generally recommended.

Comment: By who? Why do they recommend it?

Comment: @DJClayworth In case you get stuck in the country for some unforeseen reason and then your passport expires while you're in the country, leaving you in a precarious situation.

Comment: @DJClayworth since many countries *do* have a six-month rule, traveling with a passport that has less than six months' validity makes it more likely that problems could arise in the event of an unforseen need to change travel plans.