# Can my child make a 3-week round trip from Canada to India and then back to Canada with an Indian passport less than 6 months to expire?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Can my child who is 4 years old make a 3-week round trip from Canada to India and then back to Canada with an Indian passport less than 6 months to expire?

Comment: Related - For Canada- India trip - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159511/travel-to-india-with-indian-passport-having-less-than-6-months-validity . For India-Canada trip - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131322/can-i-travel-to-canada-if-my-visa-and-passport-expire-a-month-after-i-plan-to-le

Comment: What does the child have to proof right to enter Canada.

Comment: Is your child a Canadian citizen or permanent resident?